# How to search a specific variable in various type of array using generic method?

Tags: java, arrays, generics, search, generic-collections

I am trying to return a specific variable in various types of array, which i only can use generic method. However, when I try to do a search method, I keep getting this error. Is there anyone can give me some idea how do you fix it?

I am using drjava.

This is the calling statement:

```
 System.out.printf( "%nThe item returned from integerArray is: %s",
                      returnItem( integerArray,
                                  2 ) );

  System.out.printf( "%nThe item returned from doubleArray is: %s",
                      returnItem( doubleArray,
                                  2 ) );

  System.out.printf( "%nThe item returned from characterArray is: %s",
                      returnItem( characterArray,
                                  2 ) );

  System.out.printf( "%nThe item returned from petArray is: %s",
                      returnItem( petArray,
                                  2 ) );
```

This is my search method:

```
public static < T> int returnItem( T[ ] inputArray, int key ){

        // ERROR: incompatible types: T cannot be converted to int

    for ( int element : inputArray ){

        if( key == element ){

           return element;
       }
     }
       return -1;


} // end method returnItem
```

The item returned from integerArray is: 3

The item returned from integerArray is: 3.3

The item returned from integerArray is: L

Comment: What should the method `returnItem` return? The index, or the element itself?

Comment: the element itself

Comment: Why is that useful, if you already know the element and pass it to the method, to look for it in an array and return it?

Comment: To fix your method you should just change all `int` declarations to `T` to make them generic.

Answer (score 0):

@Noone, I will suggest you create a class with expected data type as parameter and arry time as argument in the construtor. Then your generic return item by key or return key by item can world.

If it is not too much. Consider my implementation below:

````
public final class SearchAnyArray<T> {

    T[] inputArray;

    public SearchAnyArray(final String[] stringArray) {
        inputArray = (T[]) stringArray;
    }

    public SearchAnyArray(final int[] integerPrimitives) {
        Integer[] ints = new Integer[integerPrimitives.length];
        for (int x = 0; x < integerPrimitives.length; x++) {
            ints[x] = integerPrimitives[x];
        }
        inputArray = (T[]) ints;
    }

    public SearchAnyArray(final double[] doublePrimitives) {
        Double[] doubles = new Double[doublePrimitives.length];
        for (int x = 0; x < doublePrimitives.length; x++) {
            doubles[x] = doublePrimitives[x];
        }
        inputArray = (T[]) doubles;
    }

    public SearchAnyArray(char[] charPrimitives) {
        Character[] chars = new Character[charPrimitives.length];
        for (int x = 0; x < charPrimitives.length; x++) {
            chars[x] = charPrimitives[x];
        }
        inputArray = (T[]) chars;
    }

    public int returnItemIndex(T key) {
        for (int x = 0; x < inputArray.length; x++) {
            if (inputArray[x].equals(key)) {
                return x;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public T returnItem(int index) {
        if (index < 0 || index > (inputArray.length - 1)) {
            throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException("Invalid key ");
        }
        return inputArray[index];
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = {1, 4, 3, 9};
        double[] d = {1.0, 4.1, 3.3, 9.4};
        char[] c = "ALLOWEDforReal".toCharArray();
        String[] s = {"Any", "How", "Is", "a", "goal"};
        System.out.println(new SearchAnyArray<>(a).returnItem(2));
        System.out.println(new SearchAnyArray<>(d).returnItem(2));
        System.out.println(new SearchAnyArray<>(c).returnItem(2));
        System.out.println(new SearchAnyArray<>(s).returnItem(2));

        System.out.println(new SearchAnyArray<>(a).returnItemIndex(3));
        System.out.println(new SearchAnyArray<>(d).returnItemIndex(3.3));
        System.out.println(new SearchAnyArray<>(c).returnItemIndex('L'));
        System.out.println(new SearchAnyArray<>(s).returnItemIndex("Is"));

    }
}```
````